# How to assess Random Forests classifier performance?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I recently started using a random forest implementation in Python using the scikit learn [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).  There is a sample script that I found on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/forest-cover-type-prediction) to classify landcover using Random Forests (see below) that I am trying to use to hone my skills.  I am interested in assessing the results of the random forests classification.

For example, if I were to perform the analysis using `randomForest` in R, I would assess the variable importance with `varImpPlot()` from the `randomForest` package:

```
require(randomForests)
...
myrf = randomForests(predictors, response)
varImpPlot(myrf)
```

And to get an idea of the out-of-box estimate of error rate and the error matrix for the classification, I would simply type 'myrf' into the interpreter.

*How can I programmatically assess these error metrics using Python?*

Note, that I am aware there are several potentially useful attributes in the documentation (e.g. `feature_importances_`, `oob_score_`, and `oob_decision_function_`), although I am not sure how to actually apply these.

---

Sample RF Script

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import ensemble

if __name__ == "__main__":
  loc_train = "kaggle_forest\\train.csv"
  loc_test = "kaggle_forest\\test.csv"
  loc_submission = "kaggle_forest\\kaggle.forest.submission.csv"

  df_train = pd.read_csv(loc_train)
  df_test = pd.read_csv(loc_test)

  feature_cols = [col for col in df_train.columns if col not in ['Cover_Type','Id']]

  X_train = df_train[feature_cols]
  X_test = df_test[feature_cols]
  y = df_train['Cover_Type']
  test_ids = df_test['Id']

  clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500, n_jobs = -1)

  clf.fit(X_train, y)

  with open(loc_submission, "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write("Id,Cover_Type\n")
    for e, val in enumerate(list(clf.predict(X_test))):
      outfile.write("%s,%s\n"%(test_ids[e],val))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for.  Are you trying to find the feature importances or the fpr/tpr?  If the latter, the answer below will get you those, but if you're looking for the former, you can use clf.feature_importances_ which will give you a vector of importances, which correspond to the features you put into the model.

Answer (score 3):

After training, if you have test data and labels, you could check accuracy and generate an ROC plot/ AUC score via:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# overall accuracy
acc = clf.score(X_test,Y_test)

# get roc/auc info
Y_score = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(Y_test, Y_score)

roc_auc = dict()
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

# make the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='AUC = {0}'.format(roc_auc))        
plt.legend(loc="lower right", shadow=True, fancybox =True) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'decision_function'

Answer (score 0):

Some basic metrics that you could use are accuracy, f1 score, and Area Under the Receiver Operating Characteristic Curve, which are all available in the sklearn library.

You can find metrics available in the sklearn library [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#classification-metrics).